# How to add .h/.o already compiled libraries in CMake

Tags: c, gcc, cmake

Seems like an easy problem but I can't seem to find any resource on this...

My project tree is simple: main.c includes list.h, the end.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(as03)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.c list.h)

add_executable(as03 ${SOURCE_FILES} list.o)
```

This CMakeLists.txt file gives error:

```
/home/.../clion-2017.1.2/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /home/shawn/CLionProjects/CMPT300/as03/cmake-build-debug --target all -- -j 4
[ 50%] Linking C executable as03
/usr/bin/ld: ../list.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against undefined symbol `headlist' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/as03.dir/build.make:96: recipe for target 'as03' failed
make[2]: *** [as03] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/as03.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/as03.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

---

**EDIT:** Environment is CLion IDE on Linux with gcc 6.3.0.

**EDIT2:** My apologies, the

```
relocation R_X86_64_32S against undefined symbol `headlist' can not be used when making a shared object
```

error is not an issue of CMake, but was reproducible with command-line compiling of the corresponding makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-w -std=c11
PROG=simulation-app
OBJS= main.o list.o

simulation-app: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(PROG) $(OBJS)

main.o: main.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c main.c


clean:
    ls | grep -v list.o | grep .o | xargs rm
```

Turns out one of my peers have encountered this problem and was solved by re-installing a fresh linux-distro...  No thanks.

So it seems like a machine-dependent problem. I have tried downgraded my gcc version to 5.4.1 to match the machine where this .o was compiled on, but nothing changed :(

Comment: 1) Remove `list.o` from `SOURCE_FILES` *and* from `as03` dependencies. 2) Read some beginners tutorial on CMake, these are rather short and self-descriptive.

Comment: As error message suggests, you should recompile your `list.o` with `-fPIC` option enabled. Also, you have *duplicate* `list.o` item in the executable's sources: one as part of *SOURCE_FILES* variable, and one direct. As for specifying header file in source list, it is normally *not required*.

Comment: @iehrlich thanks, corrected but with no change in error message :(

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks, but as you mentioned in \@utopia's answer, the file is pre-compiled, period. I tried to include -fPIC flag in makefile without any change in in error message. I think gcc recompiles it with the flag automatically for me.

Answer (score 1):

`add_executable(as03 main.c list.c)`

You should only use sources in the list after the target, not object files.

You also don't need headers in the list unless you use or want to support IDEs (especially Visual Studio).

Comment: According to the question's title, the question is specifically about using **already compiled** object file `list.o`. So using `list.c` in source list is not an option.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! As @Tsyvarev points out, I do not have possession of the .c source file, so I cannot compile this library myself sadly.